# Authentication login with Swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger

I am using `Swagger UI` for interactive `REST` endpoints representation. However, `Swagger UI` can be accessed by everyone who knows its URL. Is there any standard way to restrict `Swagger UI` access with user login.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> 
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId> 
    <version>LATEST</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> 
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId> 
    <version>LATEST</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId> 
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId> 
    <version>LATEST</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is outside of swagger's concern. You would just use your normal `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to control permissions to the swagger-ui.html URL. Would also be pretty confusing if you used different ways of configuring security IMO.

Example

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");
     }
}
```

But that's if you wan't to do security based on URLs, you could just as much do controller based security, and security on your services if they were involved but they aren't in this case. Security is very much application specific. I can't say do it this way, you might not even want to use Spring Security at all, and just do your own thing, it's just another framework to make your life easier, you could just as easily access the current logged in user in the view resolver for the `swagger-ui.html` view and throw an Unauthorised exception or something like that.

Comment: Have you an example please ?